# What does 'd' stands for in - move(double dx, double dy)?

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I am reading a java doc for GObject /acm.graphics.

I am looking at this method:

```
move(double dx, double dy)
```

Moves the object on the screen using the displacements dx and dy.

I am trying to understand what does the 'd' stands for and what is the difference between (dx,dy)  Vs (x,y)? Is there any difference or there is none and it is only a different name for the same coordinates?

Comment: It's just the name of the parameters. The d could stand for delta, difference, differential, displacement, etc... It doesn't really matter does it?

Comment: `d` may stands for difference. `(dx, dy)` stands for change in x - coordinate and y - coordinates (relative to current). While (x, y) is commonly used to represent absolute location.

Comment: `d` stands for *delta*

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `move(double dx, double dy)` Moves the object on the screen using the displacements `dx` and `dy`.

In this context `dx` would be "displacement on the x-axis" and `dy` would be "displacement on the y-axis". The method would move the object `dx` units along the x-axis, and `dy` units along the y-axis, where the units are presumably pixels.